# How do I know a USB Bluetooth Adapter is safe to use?

Tags: malware, usb, bluetooth, trojan

I've found several extremely cheap USB Bluetooth options and, while the reviews say they work, I am skeptical of them because they are so cheap/have no name brand recognition.

Here is the main one I am looking at: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B071WKP37Q/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071WKP37Q)

My real question: How do I know this isn't a sort of trojan horse that functions as described but also adds malicious software to my computer without me knowing/at the same time?

The device would have to have some kind of flash memory on board, and who knows what will load when plugged in. I doubt Amazon is doing any kind of testing, so I need to put faith in the third-party company (Lovin Product) selling it, which is, according to their website, 'an importer and distributor of wireless products...' (not the manufacturer)

Not trying to call out this company/product in particular, just curious if anyone has thoughts on this. Am I overthinking this, or are these legitimate concerns?

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't know it. At most you know that a device is definitely unsafe to use but you'll never know if a device is fully safe to use. Possible duplicate of [How do we cross-verify if the device is doing exactly what it is supposed to do?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219641/how-do-we-cross-verify-if-the-device-is-doing-exactly-what-it-is-supposed-to-do)

Comment: Thanks for link, didn't see that post.